# Unable to post on a Facebook page using Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post on my page using Facebook Graph API.
I added `pages_manage_posts` successfully and generated an access token, then made a POST request

`https://graph.facebook.com/{page_id}/feed?message=Hello&access_token={page_access_token}` but it always returns following error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) If posting to a group, requires app being installed in the group, and \
          either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both pages_read_engagement \
          and pages_manage_posts permission with page token; If posting to a page, \
          requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts as an admin with \
          sufficient administrative permission",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "AsKMEdaa8OGp1DX8uK8QRP-"
  }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Error message mentions two permissions you need, you said you did get one …

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, I've already fixed this, I was using `user_access_token` instead of `page_access_token`